# How to access Class member variables from SpringApplication in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How do you access a member variable when starting the application using SpringApplication in SpringBoot ?

In the below code I am getting compilation errors on the assignment to `Environment` and `BuildProperties`. I think there must be a way to reference these properties via the `SpringApplication` or `ConfigurableApplicationContext` but I don't know how.

The compile error I am getting is, 
`non-static variable environment cannot be referenced from a static context`
which I understand its just how to get around it.

I think my question really is - does SpringApplication return a Class level reference in the same way as doing a normal java MyClass myClass = new MyClass() does ?

```
@Slf4j
@EnableIntegration
@EnableLoaderApplication
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class ExampleApplication {

    private Environment environment;
    private BuildProperties buildProperties;

    public ExampleApplication(Environment env, BuildProperties buildProp) {
        environment = env;
        buildProperties = buildProp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(ExampleApplication.class);
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = app.run(args);

        environment = context.getEnvironment();  //compile error
        buildProperties = context.getBean(BuildProperties.class); //compile error

    DisplaySysInfo displaySysInfo = new DisplaySysInfo(environment, buildProperties, log);
    displaySysInfo.splash();

    }

}
```

Comment: Why you need to access such variables from the main method ?

Comment: because I am instantiating another class and passing these values to it... I've updated my code example to show this incase it helps to clarify the problem.

In a normal Java program I would simply instantiate the Class and then reference the member variables through the class - but since I am going via Spring this is not possible.

Comment: I think my question really is - does SpringApplication return a Class level reference in the same way as doing a normal java `MyClass myClass = new MyClass()` does ?

Comment: I don't know why you say "You cannot have a compile error on two lines at the same time", or " FOR SURE doesn't come from any of the lines you marked here" - for both of those statements I would have to say that's not correct. I do have the compilation error mentioned and they are on both lines. I don't think its a surprise. Even if this was a normal Java application I would expect the same compile errors - since I am trying to reference member variables through static context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Either inject Environment in your DisplaySysInfo class

```
@Autowire
Environment env;
```

Or retrieve environment from the context itself

```
 ConfigurableApplicationContext run = SpringApplication.run(ExampleApplication.class, args);
 ConfigurableEnvironment environment = run.getEnvironment();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I am answering to your question

> "I think my question really is - does SpringApplication return a Class level reference in the same way as doing a normal java MyClass myClass = new MyClass() does ?"

Short Answer is **No**, *Spring* doesn't return the reference to object instance like new MyClass() does. When you use *spring context* you get references to *Beans* that are actually proxies to *something like normal classes*.
I suggest you read more about DI and spring components, here there is a [spring_bean_definition](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_definition.htm) mini tutorial. The tutorial is a bit old, and make use of the xml notation to declare beans, but concepts and definition are still valid.

Hope this could help.

Answer (score 0):

Having this kind of logic inside your main class is never a good practice, instead of this, you can use @PostConstruct to initiate a new Bean just after finish the initial bean injections and configurations of your program. 
So, you can move this logic to another class with @PostConstruct:

```
environment = context.getEnvironment();  //compile error
buildProperties = context.getBean(BuildProperties.class); //compile error
```

this way, you are not getting any static context error and your code will be cleaner.